# Converting java list to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Helllo,
I am trying to send a list of Objects from spring controller and using that list in javascript from jsp in order to make a chart.
 Since javascript is taking the list as a string, can anyone suggest me a proper method of doing this. 
Im trying to use this list to iterate in order to put values for a chart...

```
List list=WebKinmelServiceManager.select("select i From Item i", Item.class);\
        mav.addObject("list", list);
```

and i want to display in jsp page inside javascript in this format..

```
$scope.data = {
    series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense'],
    data : [{
        x : "Jack",
        y: [100,210, 384],
        tooltip:"this is tooltip"
    },
    {
        x : "John",
        y: [300, 289, 456]
    },
    {
        x : "Stacy",
        y: [351, 170, 255]
    },
    {
        x : "Luke",
        y: [54, 341, 879]
    }]     
}
```

Would really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found some libraries here which can be easily imported](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

My code went something like

My Controller

```
JSONArray series=new JSONArray();
            series.put("Quantitiy");
            series.put("Price");
        mav.addObject("series", series);
        JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
        List list=WebKinmelServiceManager.select("select i From Item i", Item.class);
        for (Object object : list) {
            Item item=(Item) object;
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("x", item.getName());
                JSONArray array2=new JSONArray();
                array2.put(item.getQuantity());
                array2.put(item.getPrice());
            jsonObject.put("y", array2);

            array.put(jsonObject);
        }
        mav.addObject("data", array);
```

And my Javascript went like

```
var data=${data};
var series=${series}
$scope.data = {
    series: series,
    data : data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this way
-> Java list to JSON( here is good library for that )

https://github.com/google/gson

here is the sample code

```
List<SomeObject> objList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
objList.add(new SomeObject());

//make json string
new Gson().toJson( objList );
```

Comment: Could you please mention how to use that object in javascript

Comment: `var jsonString = '{"result":true,"count":1}'; var jsonObj =JSON.parse(json); console.log(jsonObj.result); console.log(jsonObj.count); `

you can access any property and value, like a javascript object.